# Product of a linearly dependent and a lineraly independent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If I multiply matrix $A×B$ where $A$ is a matrix of $5 × 4$ and $B$ is a matrix of $4 × 5$ and thus has at least one linearly dependent row, can I conclude the same for matrix $AB$? i.e, matrix $AB$ has at least one lineraly dependent row?

Comment: $AB$ product is undefined. Pay close attention to the dimensions of your matrices.

Comment: @eminem I think the product is of $A^* B$, so it is defined.

Comment: re-edited so that the product is defined, sry for the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows of $AB$ will also be linearly dependent. **Proof**: The rows of the matrix $AB$ are linear combinations of the rows of the matrix $B$. If the latter span at most a $4$-dimensional space, the former will also span at most a $4$-dimensional space.

---

The statement that the rows of the matrix $AB$ are linear combinations of the rows of the matrix $B$ is a well-known fact, and is valid for any size matrices over any commutative ring. Namely, if:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\cdots&a_{mn}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}&\cdots&b_{1p}\\b_{21}&b_{22}&\cdots&b_{2p}\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\b_{n1}&b_{n2}&\cdots&b_{np}\end{bmatrix}$$

then:

$$AB=\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^na_{1i}b_{i1}&\sum_{i=1}^na_{1i}b_{i2}&\cdots&\sum_{i=1}^na_{1i}b_{ip}\\\sum_{i=1}^na_{2i}b_{i1}&\sum_{i=1}^na_{2i}b_{i2}&\cdots&\sum_{i=1}^na_{2i}b_{ip}\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\\sum_{i=1}^na_{mi}b_{i1}&\sum_{i=1}^na_{mi}b_{i2}&\cdots&\sum_{i=1}^na_{mi}b_{ip}\end{bmatrix}$$

and if you denote the rows of the matrix $B$ as follows:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\mathfrak{b_1}&=&\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}&\cdots&b_{1p}\end{bmatrix}\\ \mathfrak{b_2}&=&\begin{bmatrix}b_{21}&b_{22}&\cdots&b_{2p}\end{bmatrix}\\&\vdots&\\\mathfrak{b_n}&=&\begin{bmatrix}b_{n1}&b_{n2}&\cdots&b_{np}\end{bmatrix}\end{array}$$

notice that the rows of the matrix $AB$ are as follows:

$$\begin{array}{l}a_{11}\mathfrak {b_1}+a_{12}\mathfrak{b_2}+\ldots+a_{1n}\mathfrak{b_n}\\a_{21}\mathfrak{b_1}+a_{22}\mathfrak{b_2}+\ldots+a_{2n}\mathfrak{b_n}\\\vdots\\a_{m1}\mathfrak{b_1}+a_{m2}\mathfrak{b_2}+\ldots+a_{mn}\mathfrak{b_n}\end{array}$$

where the coefficients that multiply the rows of $B$ to obtain the rows of $AB$ are precisely the entries of the matrix $A$.

(If this is not immediately clear to you, I suggest you expand some of the sums in the expression for $AB$ and convince yourselves that the rows of $AB$ are as above. Or, try a concrete example with small, e.g. $3\times 2$ and $2\times 3$ matrices.)

Note also that there is a similar statement: the *columns* of the matrix $AB$ are linear combinations of the *columns* of the matrix $A$. (Proof: similar to the one above.)

Comment: can you show a proof or explain further?

Comment: @ceins Which bit do you think you don't understand? The bit where I claim that the rows of $AB$ are linear combinations of the rows of $B$, or the bit where I analyse the dimensions?

Comment: the first one, thank you!

Comment: @ceins Updated the proof. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix you are considering seems to be $A^*B$, where $A^*$ is the Hermitian transpose.

Thus $A^*B$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix. The given data is insufficient to conclude, because $A^*B$ can have any rank from $0$ to $4$.

Indeed, taking $B=A$, we can prove that the rank of $A^*A$ is the same as the rank of $A$.